# Numerically stable method for angle between 3D vectors

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm looking for a numerically stable method for computing the angle between two 3D vectors. Which of the following methods ought to be preferred?

Method 1:
$$
u\times v = ||u||~||v|| \sin(\theta) \textbf{n}\\
u\cdot v = ||u||~||v|| \cos(\theta)\\
\theta = \arctan2(||u\times v||,~u\cdot v)
$$

Method 2:

$$
\theta = 2~\arctan2(||u/||u|| - v/||v||~||,~||u/||u|| + v/||v||~||)
$$

where method 2 is based on the fact that the sum and difference vectors of two unit (or equal length) vectors are orthogonal.

Or is there an even better method which I haven't thought of? The vectors I am considering have angles typically smaller than 2 degrees.

Comment: I guess you mean $2\,\mathrm{atan2}(\|u/\|u\|-v/\|v\|\|,\|u/\|u\|+v/\|v\|\|)$ in method 2?

Answer (score 15):

Short answer: Method 2 is better for small angles. Use this slight rearrangement:
$$
\theta = 2~atan2(||~||v||u - ||u||v~||,~||~||v||u + ||u||v~||)
$$

This formula comes from W. Kahan's advice in his paper "How Futile are Mindless Assessments of Roundoff in Floating-Point Computation?" (https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Mindless.pdf), section 12 "Mangled Angles."

Before I found that paper, I also did my own analysis, comparing the double-precision results with result's using bc with 50 digits of precision. Method 2 is commonly within 1 ulp of correct, and almost always within 50 ulps, whereas Method 1 was much, much less accurate.

This might seem surprising, since Method 1 is mathematically insensitive to the magnitude of u and v, whereas they have to be normalized in Method 2. And indeed, the accuracy of the normalization is the limiting factor for Method 2 - virtually all the error comes from the fact that even after normalization, the vectors aren't *exactly* length 1.

However, for small angles you get catastrophic cancellation in the cross product for method 1. Specifically, all the products like $u_y v_z - u_z v_y$ end up close to 0, and I believe the cross-multiplication before the subtraction loses accuracy, compared to the direct subtraction in Method 2.

Comment: What about the common method $\arccos(\frac{u \cdot v}{|| u || || v ||})$?

Comment: That's possibly the worst choice for small angles. $\frac{u \cdot v}{||u||||v||}$ approaches 1 for small angles, so you lose most of your precision.

Comment: @D0SBoots 
I came to this question and your answer because I was indeed in crossroads trying to understand which algorithm should I use.

You mention "catastrophic cancellation in the cross product" and also "ulp" (unit of least precision?) but I would like to realize these on my end. I've made this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77610266/which-algorithm-is-more-accurate-for-calculation-of-the-angle-between-3d-vectors  And would like to grasp why indeed Method2 is better than Method1, even though I'm more biased towards Method1. Thanks