# Angle between vectors from vector coordinates.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to compute the angle between vectors by means of the formula given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143354/numerically-stable-method-for-angle-between-3d-vectors),

$$
\theta = 2\arctan2 \left( \left|\left| \frac{\textbf{y}}{\|\textbf{y}\|} - \frac{\textbf{x}}{\|\textbf{x}\|} \right|\right|,
\left|\left| \frac{\textbf{y}}{\|\textbf{y}\|} + \frac{\textbf{x}}{\|\textbf{x}\|}\right|\right| \right)
$$

Provided that I have the coordinates of $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ in the basis $B$.
Intuitively makes no sense to explicitly perform the change of basis but I cannot find the proper expression.

Concretely, my problem is,

Given a basis $B=\{  \textbf{u},\textbf{v},\textbf{w}\}$, I want to compute the angle between vectors $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ which are given by,

$$\textbf{x} = \alpha\textbf{u}+\beta\textbf{v}+\gamma\textbf{w}$$
$$\textbf{y} = \delta\textbf{u}+\epsilon\textbf{v}+\zeta\textbf{w}$$

without explicitly perform the change of basis first.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think a change of basis is required. The formula for $\theta$ is already basis independent (as you would expect, since $\theta$ does not depend on the basis chosen). All you need to do is to find $||\textbf{x}||$ and $||\textbf{y}||$.

Comment: Yes, but the question is, can I obtain $\theta$ without the basis B?

Comment: @gandalf61 Maybe this is not the proper formula to use? Maybe there are some conditions the basis has to fulfil (like being ON)? I am a bit confused but how to I compute $\|x\|$ and  $\|y\|$ otherwise?

Comment: You can’t do this unless the basis is orthogonal.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Exactly, that's what i was finding. But then I thought does it even need to be orthonormal? Or orthogonal is enough?

Comment: Well you don't really need to have the basis but in any case you need at least the gram matrix $B^TB$ to compute the norms and/or dot products from coordinates.

Comment: I think I understood now, indeed if the basis is ON the coordinates give the right angle.

Comment: I wonder whoever downvoted most likely didn't really understand the question in the first place, or would be good to have any feedback otherwise.